# Python Column Parser for Keyword Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, keyword

The following link is a data source example of what I'm trying to parse.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/wfri4idoxszqixs/sampleWordData.xlsx

I have a column with words of value in them.  I want to parse each word for the row and append the amount column to them.  For example:

Original Dataframe 
Words (Col 1), Amount (Col 2) 
Words = ['Google', 'Google is awesome', 'Hi Google'] 
Amount = [5, 10, 5]

New Dataframe 
Word1 (Col 1), Word2 (Col 2), Word3 (Col 3), Amount (Col 4) 
Word1 = ['Google', 'Google', 'Hi'] 
Word2 = ['', 'is', 'Google'] 
Word3 = ['', 'awesome', ''] 
Amount = [5, 10, 5]

Final Dataframe 
Word = ['Google', 'is', 'awesome', 'Hi'] 
Amount = [15, 10, 10, 5]

Tried the best I could to explain as struggled to get markdown to play nice with a column format.  I show each step in the xlsx as to how I'm trying to transform the data.

My following attempt at the code:

```
import pandas as pd

#load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.columns = ('words', 'amount')
df.head()

#toget rid of nulls
df.dropna(subset=['words', inplace=True)

#shows me how many columns are needed in total to encompass the longest line
print(df.words.str.split(expand=True).head() 

#attempt to split out the first word from the bunch of words per row
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.words.str.split(' ', 1).tolist(),
                                  columns = ['word1', 'word2']
```

Would appreciate any help or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can give you a more elegant method.

- Split each string of words into a list, in a new column, called `words`.
- Multiply these lists by the column `Amount`, then request their counts using `Counter`.
- Aggregate these counts across records using an external function, `aggregator`.
- Finally construct the new Dataframe using the aggregated data.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def aggregator(counter):
    for k in counter.keys():
        result[k]+=counter[k]

df = pd.read_excel('sampleWordData.xlsx', header=0)
df['words'] = df['Word'].str.split()
df['counts'] = (df['words']*df['Amount']).apply(Counter)
result = defaultdict(int)
df.counts.apply(aggregator)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'words': list(result.keys()), 'counts': list(result.values())})
print (new_df)
```

Printed result:

```
   counts    words
0      20   Google
1      10       is
2      10  awesome
3       5       Hi
```